# After running a new URLSearchParams, params.get() returning null

Tags: javascript

Hello i have an api call to a netlify function which looks like the following:

```
exports.handler = async(event,context) => {

const params = new URLSearchParams(event.body)
...
}
```

consoling params returns

```
'{"items":[{"id":"prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ"}]}', ''
```

when I try to put the `items` value in to a variable with

```
const items = params.get('items')
```

`items` returns `null`

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the type of `event.body`?

Comment: Those are not search params. That looks like regular JSON. Search params would be something like `items=prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ`

Comment: event.body = string

Answer (score 0):

You've put the wrong format of data inside the params. Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) you need to add the parameters in one of the ways they mention here.

(From the documentation)

> One of:
>
> - A string, which will be parsed from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. A leading `'?'` character is
>   ignored.
> - A literal sequence of name-value string pairs, or any object — such as a `FormData` object — with an iterator that produces a sequence of
>   string pairs. Note that `File` entries will be serialized as `[object File]` rather than as their filename (as they would in an
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form).
> - A record of string keys and string values. **Note that nesting is not supported.**

i.e

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({"id": "prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ"});
```

Rather than accessing items to get all the params which doesn't work.